# Ultra-low power solar cell help

Tags: capacitor, adc, solar-cell

I need your help…

Scenario:
Use case aside, I have an ultra-low power source (1.5v solar cell) and it is charging a 10uF cap.  The solar cell is in a highly controlled low light environment with well-regulated ambient light variables.  Let me know if you want to learn more, I can share a GitHub.

Setup:
Every 10 seconds for 600 seconds, I take two measurements, one of the caps voltage and the other across a 100kohm resistor inline with the solar cell.
I am using a Raspberry Pi and some relays to “tap into” the charging circuit, take a quick measurement and “tap out” as to reduce the impedance of the ADC as much as possible. With these low voltages and currents, every little bit counts.  I am using a 16bit ADC on the Raspberry Pi to take the voltage measurements (5Mohm impedance).  All voltage measurements I have are validated accurate on the ADC w/ a Fluke 110(5Mohm impedance). Yes, I am using the voltage drop across the resistor to calculate current.

Circuit diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGKaG.png

Question:
My question, based on this plot below (177, 10-minute tests), it appears the voltage of the cap is very consistent as it charges over 600 seconds.  However, the current is not perfectly inversely proportional to the voltage.  Furthermore, there seems to be extreme variance from 320 to 380 nanoamps.  Why is the current not behaving as consistent and predictable as voltage? Or am “too zoomed in” on the current and should be looking at it from an A or mA perspective and not a nA lens? Is a variance of 60 nA considered “Consistent”?

Plot of voltage and current: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j80gE.png

Comment: I wouldn't consider your setup to be capable of reliably measuring to a precision of nanoamps. That's a really tiny current, and can very easily be swamped by noise. Are you synchronizing your measurements to be an integer number of power line cycles? Are you shielding *everything* and using triaxial cable for the current-carrying paths, with buffer amplifiers to prevent leakage through the cable dielectric? Sixty nanoamps of noise is well within the realm of believability if you don't take such steps.

Comment: Thank you @Hearth! This is the feedback I was looking for, ok so this is expected at this scale ya? I am taking 50 measurements each and averaging it. However I think you are correct there may be some noise. didn't realize that it was this visible at the nA scale. Thank you again @Hearth

Comment: The one thing you can probably do easily to improve your measurement is to use an integration time that's synchronized to the power line, since power line noise is a substantial portion of any noise you'll see in things like this. Not all of it, by any means--you'll get a lot of Johnson-Nyquist noise from that huge 100 kΩ resistor, for instance--but you can cut it down a lot (much more than naïve averaging of multiple measurements) if you integrate for an integer number of power line cycles.

Comment: Amazing feedback @Hearth! Thank you again! I will try this for sure! For a small number of measurements I did observe patterns that were untill now unexplainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This variance is interference from noise, probably line voltage field [V/m] without an RF  cap to suppress it.  with 1/6th of the current as noise using Vpp ratios using 5Mohm, we can say the interfence makes a signal/noise ratio of 6:1

It  could be suppressed  with a capacitor impedance ratio using 20 dB/decade of f above the breakpoint using 20 log [1/{2pi f * RC}]  for the interfering frequency.  But Scope probes may also attenuate with 10pF//10M and earth ground .

My guess is it is 160Vpp 60Hz Line noise attenuated by stray reactance or relay inductive noise.
You can use a large cap or wire from 0V to PE earth to suppress it.

50 measurements may reduce the noise by 7. .Twisted pairs or STP wire, grounding and RF caps can reduce more.  A "Twin-T" notch filter can reduce it by >99%.

Shorting a relay < 2A will slowly burn off the gold plating, but is good for burning off oxide rust on contacts >2A with no gold plating.
[image]

Here is one shown using RC for 60 Hz using high R values. [image]  Log sweep 55 to 65 Hz 100 ms triangle sweep.

Comment: This is amazing feedback! Thank you @Tony! So far this is the second suggestion that I need to isolate, earth, and adjust my setup a tiny bit. You have an amazing point with that relay noise too! Didn't think of that!  Thank you @Tony! Very grateful for your guidance and experience!

Comment: Thank you again @Tony! You have imparted a level of wisdom I crave! Thank you. Everything you shared has taught me so much! Excited to try these recommendations as well as save my relay.